# Python: Maximum of lists of 2 or more elements in a tuple using key

Tags: python, python-2.7, max

Lets say i have a tuple of list like:

```
g = (['20', '10'], ['10', '74'])
```

I want the max of two based on the first value in each list like

```
max(g, key = ???the g[0] of each list.something that im clueless what to provide)
```

And answer is ['20', '10']
Is that possible? what should be the key here?
According to above answer.

Another eg:

```
g = (['42', '50'], ['30', '4'])
ans: max(g, key=??) = ['42', '50']
```

PS: By max I mean numerical maximum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just pass in a callable that gets the first element of each item. Using [`operator.itemgetter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) is easiest:

```
from operator import itemgetter

max(g, key=itemgetter(0))
```

but if you *have* to test against integer values instead of lexographically sorted items, a lambda might be better:

```
max(g, key=lambda k: int(k[0]))
```

Which one you need depends on what you expect the maximum to be for strings containing digits of differing length. Is `'4'` smaller or larger than `'30'`?

Demo:

```
>>> g = (['42', '50'], ['30', '4'])
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> max(g, key=itemgetter(0))
['42', '50']
>>> g = (['20', '10'], ['10', '74'])
>>> max(g, key=itemgetter(0))
['20', '10']
```

or showing the difference between `itemgetter()` and a `lambda` with `int()`:

```
>>> max((['30', '10'], ['4', '10']), key=lambda k: int(k[0]))
['30', '10']
>>> max((['30', '10'], ['4', '10']), key=itemgetter(0))
['4', '10']
```

Comment: max(([30, 10], [4, 10]), key=operator.itemgetter(0)) = [30, 10] would work if it were int.as ive stated in ashwini's case, itemgetter would be an overkill here. Thanks

Comment: `itemgetter()` would be *insufficient* here, not overkill. :-) `itemgetter()` is a lot faster than a `lambda` but it doesn't fit your usecase.

Comment: what i mean is lambda is preferred knife over sword

Comment: `key=itemgetter(0)` is not required for `max((['30', '10'], ['4', '10']))` Same result in either case.

Comment: @drewk right. since Martijn offered valuable insight I was comparing max(([30, 10], [4, 10]), key=operator.itemgetter(0)) works but  Martijn'max((['30', '10'], ['4', '10'])) are strings not numbers

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lambda` to specify which item should be used for comparison:

```
>>> g = (['20', '10'], ['10', '74'])
>>> max(g, key = lambda x:int(x[0]))  #use int() for conversion
['20', '10']

>>> g = (['42', '50'], ['30', '4'])
>>> max(g, key = lambda x:int(x[0]))
['42', '50']
```

You can also use `operator.itemegtter`, but in this case it'll not work as the items are in string form.

Comment: ok great. i was doing int(x[0][0]) which was giving TypeError. Thanks.

Comment: itemgetter would, if it were int yes it would work but thats an overkill in such a minor case

Comment: @user2290820 `int(x[0][0])` was there because the pasted the wrong version. :/

Comment: ok, didnt see that.no i mean i tried that before, so it threw that error, which was ofcourse wrong.

Comment: @user2290820 Increase the number of items to 100, and `itemgetter` is twice as fast than lambda. For tiny lists, yes lambda is enough.

Comment: yes when it comes in terms of C performance, if a lib uses bulit in  __getitem__ it is.but not for trivial tasks like here

Answer (score 1):

If by 'max' you mean lexicographic max:

```
>>> max(['0','5','10','100'])
'5'
>>> min(['0','5','10','100'])
'0'
```

Then you can just use max with no key function at all:

```
>>> max((['20', '10'], ['10', '74']))
['20', '10']
>>> max((['42', '50'], ['30', '4']))
['42', '50']
```

If you mean numerical max, use a lambda:

```
>>> max((['0','10'],['5','100'],['100','1000']))
['5', '100']
>>> max((['0','10'],['5','100'],['100','1000']),key=lambda l:int(l[0]))
['100', '1000']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store numbers as numbers:

```
g = ([20, 10], [10, 74])
max(g)
```